# Escaped encoded string isn't accepted by server but hardcoded string is

Tags: swift

I'm using the following to turn a dictionary into a JSON string:

```
var toJSONString : String {

    let dictionary = self.data

    do {

        //Convert to Data
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])

        //Convert back to string. Usually only do this for debugging
        if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

            let string = JSONString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "\\\"")

            return string
        }

    } catch {

    }

    return ""

}
```

which returns a string exactly like:

```
"{\"m\":0,\"i\":2,\"n\":\"Authenticate\",\"o\":\"{\\\"Password\\\":\\\"XXXXXXXX\\\",\\\"UserName\\\":\\\"XXXX@XXXX.com\\\"}\"}"
```

The websocket I'm sending this to does not accept the string variable:

```
socket.write(String: object.toJSONString)
```

Although the string has the correct value -- I know this because if I copy that exact string into the function manually it works and I get an auth token return from websocket:

```
socket.write(String: "{\"m\":0,\"i\":2,\"n\":\"Authenticate\",\"o\":\"{\\\"Password\\\":\\\"XXXXXXXX\\\",\\\"UserName\\\":\\\"XXXX@XXXX.com\\\"}\"}")
```

There is obviously something about the encoding of the string that the websocket doesn't like and I don't understand. Variable has exact value of hard coded string but isn't accepted -- what gives?

Comment: There is no valid reason for the line that escapes the double-quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

So it works if I formatted the String variable to have a value of:

```
{"i":2,"n":"WebAuthenticateUser","o":"{\"Password\":\"Versett1234!\",\"UserName\":\"jesse@versett.com\"}","m":0}
```

I don't know why the variable needs different escaping than a hard-coded call but it works.